# How to find out which latest rollup pack you're on in ms dynamics crm 2011?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Feels like I've been running in circles but how do I found that out?  What lead me to cause was trying to install a plugin from IOTAP but the import failed.

> 'PluginType' entity doesn't contain attribute with Name =
>   'customworkflowactivityinfo'.

Any way of checking the latest rollup for CRM. I'm using 2011 that was an upgrade from 4 and it's online.

Answer (score 1):

You can find an overview of Dynamics CRM version numbers on MSDN blog [Dynamics CRM in the Field](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/08/15/microsoft-dynamics-crm-4-0-and-2011-update-rollup-release-dates-build-numbers-and-collateral.aspx).

B.t.w. rollup 14 should fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks Henk! Can I skip to rollup 14 or does it have to be consecutive?

Comment: It has been some time ago, but if I'm not wrong you must have installed RU 7 at a minimum. Just try and upgrade upto the latest RU for CRM 2011.